# How could you refactor current_user in User.query.all() in Flask-Security?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Index page should be shown only to logged in users and redirect other users to landing page.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if current_user in User.query.all():
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('landing.html')
```

So how could you refactor `current_user in User.query.all()` part? Should I customize the `@login_required` somehow? How have others dealt with this problem?

Comment: You could create a User.is_logged_in property and check if your current user is logged in. saves you from making the query altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `current_user.is_authenticated` property. e.g

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return render_template('index.html')
else:
    return render_template('landing.html')
```